# Can't understand C# windows phone 8.1 (SL) file storage

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing a simple quizz game for WP8.1, at some point I decided to add a highscore capability.
I took an option which I know is not the best one but that should work anyhow : include a highscore.txt file in my application with a default value 0 and placed this file in the "Resources" folder. When the actual score is higher than the highscore I want to overwrite.

Here is how I have proceeded :
First: a method to grab the highscore and store it in a variable (This first method works pretty fine, it reads the file and gets the highscore)

```
public async void getHighScore(){           

       Uri highScoreFileLoc = new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/Highscore.txt");
       StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(highScoreFileLoc);
      string highScoreSTR = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);    
   }
```

A method to write the highscore into the file. My thought is that if I use the same exact file path and name, I should overwrite the file I have just opened.

```
private async void ecritHighScore(int highScore)
    {           
        byte[] line = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(scoreJoueur.ToString());            
        Uri HighScoreFileLoc = new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/Highscore.txt");
        StorageFile file2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(HighScoreFileLoc);         
        string highScoreSTR = highScore.ToString();
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file2, line);           
    }
```

When I run the app, the highscore is written and read correctly the second time.
But if I quit the emulator and run it again, the highscore is back to the default value: the original Highscore.txt file was not overwritten...

To sum up the situation : 
I open a file and read it correctly but when I write into the same exact file (Uri is exactly the same), it is another file that is written into.
How is this possible ? It seems to me that I am missing something somewhere, but I could not find out...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You file uri points to the install directory which is read-only. (And your first write will probably fail on a real device.

Use an **ms-appdata://** instead, which is the apps local directory.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand well, I'm doing it wrong. I guess I should first copy my file into the localfolder and then write into it (and read the initial value only the first time the app is launched).

Comment: Right. Or read it from install dir whenever loading the file from local storage fails.